# Python while loop with !=0

Tags: python, while-loop, equals

I have problem with while loop:

```
  def ancestors(node, tree):
        ancestorsss = []
        ancestorsss.append(node.value)
        parent = node.parent
        while(parent != 0):
            parent_node = find_node(parent, tree)
            parent = parent_node.parent
            ancestors(parent_node, tree)
        return ancestorsss
```

in my example, the first parent is 4, and it should go through while loop, in second iteration parent, is 2 that's ok also, the third-time parent is 1, also ok, then parent is 0, and while loop still continues? I think it should exit when parent=0, but it does not.

Edit:
Node is object that has value and parent.
Tree is list of node objects [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 4), (9, 4)].

Now I call ancestors function with node(8,4) and think that it should go (8, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1) and (1, 0). It does not stop with (1, 0)

Edit 2:

```
def find_node(parent, tree):
    node = next((x for x in tree if x.value == parent), None)
    return node
```

Comment: It should exit. Have you verified that `parent` actually *is* `0`, and not something like `"0"`?

Comment: Is `parent==0` or is `parent.value==0`?

Comment: parent is 0, integer zero

Answer (score 0):

most likely is that the problem in the parent variable type , make sure that it's an integer or change the condition to `while parent != "0"` .

if it's none of the above you could share more details about `node` and `node.parent`

Comment: parent is integer type and parent=0.
Node is object that has value, and parent, tree is list of node objects.
Now nodes in order in functions are (8, 4), then (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), after (1, 0) where 0 is parent it should stop, but it does not.

Comment: have you tried to print the value of parent with each iteration to make sure that it takes the value 0, also try `while(int(parent)):`

Comment: again I did :). If I put print(parent) before while, i get 4 2 1 0 0 1 0 0.

Comment: Then try `while(int(parent)):` and put print(int(parent)) inside while to be sure that it ignore the condition

Comment: Somehow it still does not ignore it :)